# How to make :hover only affect lettering instead of the box?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm curious to how you make it so your :hover property will only affect the individual letters in my navigation bar instead of just hovering over the the box.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.navigation-bar {
  height: 3.2em;
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
}
.navigation-bar ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.navigation-bar li {
  display: inline;
}
.navigation-bar li a {
  color: white;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  margin: 1em 0 0 -2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  height: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
.navigation-bar li a:hover,
a:focus {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="navbar1.css">
<div class="navigation-bar">
  <div id="navigation-container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Here is an example of my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/uz081886/

Right now when hovering over a tab it shows a black bar, how do I make it so it would just highlight the letters of each word? Such as when I hover over Home, the text color will turn to black instead of white without the black bar appearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
.navigation-bar li a:hover, 
a:focus {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

to

```
.navigation-bar li a:hover, 
a:focus {
  color: #111;
}
```

This works because `background-color` targets the fill color of the element while `color` targets the color of the text.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realize it was something so simple that completely went over my head.

Comment: Anytime! How great is it when things are this simple though?

Comment: I have a follow-up question that I may ask in a separate thread. To make my navigation bar centered the best way I found was to make it an inline-block. However, doing so makes it so when I have an active tab or hover over it with background-color, it only highlights a small section. How can I make it highlight the entire section as if it weren't an inline-block? https://jsfiddle.net/uz081886/6/

Answer (score 2):

change background-color property to color property in css.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.navigation-bar {
  height: 3.2em;
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
}

.navigation-bar ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navigation-bar li {
  display: inline;
}

.navigation-bar li a {
  color: white;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  margin: 1em 0 0 -2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  height: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.navigation-bar li a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #111;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-bar">
  <div id="navigation-container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Background-color to color property in css